# Error starting up R when starting R Studio

Tags: r

I have installed R on my Ubuntu System- I am able to start R up in the terminal, but when I start R Studio I get this error message:

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.12.0+353 "Elsbeth Geranium " (7d165dcf, 2022-12-03) for Ubuntu Jammy

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2022.12.0+353 Chrome/102.0.5005.167 Electron/19.1.3 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 127.

Error output:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/rsession: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*Log File*

```
[No logs available]
```

Comment: where is your r installed ? Does `R.home()` return an error? if so rstudio might not be able to find your r installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong version downloaded. My operating system is Ubuntu 20, but I had the one for 22.

Comment: Hi Jan, I'm also running into this problem. Which version did you download?

Comment: This also happens if one compiled `R` from sources and forgot to set `--enable-R-shlib` at the `configure` commandline and do `make; make pdf; make info; make install; make install-libR`